# Strange Symbol shown in C output. Any clues?

Tags: c, data-structures, prefix, infix-notation

I am trying to write a code for conversion from Infix to prefix. Here it is:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int top = -1, size;

int precedence(char c)
{
    if (c=='+' || c=='-')
        return 1;
    if (c=='*' || c=='/')
        return 2;
        if (c=='^')
        return 3;
}



/* push the given data into the stack */
void push(char *stack, char data) {
    top++;
    //printf("Top:%d, Size:%d\n",top,size);
    if (top >= size ) {
        printf("Stack Overflow\n");
        return;
    }

    //printf("Hello in PUSH\n");
    stack[top] = data;
    return;
}

/* pop the top element from the stack */
void pop(char *stack) {
    if (top <= -1) {
        printf("Stack Underflow!\n");
        return;
    }
    stack[top] = '*';
    top--;
    return;
}
char peek(char *stack)
{
    return stack[top];
}
void stackp(char *stack)
{
    int r;
printf("Print Stack:\n");
for(r=0;r<top;r++)
    printf("%c\n",stack[r]);
}


int main()
{
    char data;
    char ip[100];
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter the Input, Input can be of max 100 characters:\n");
    scanf("%s", ip);
    size=strlen(ip);
    char op[size];
    char stack[size];
    for(i=size-1;i>-1;i--)
    {

        stackp(stack);// Print Stack
        //printf("Hello\n");
            //printf("%c ",ip[i]);// Print current element
            if((ip[i]-'0')>0 && (ip[i]-'0')<9)
            {
       // printf("Hello\n");
            strcat(op,&ip[i]);
        printf("%s \n",op);
            break;
            }
        else if(top==-1)
            {
                push(stack,ip[i]);
                break;
            }
        else if(top!=-1 && ip[i]==')')// Brackets Condition
        {
            while(stack[top]!='(')
                {
                     strcat(op,&ip[i]);
                     pop(stack);
                }

        }
        else if(top!=-1 && (precedence(stack[top])-precedence(ip[i])>0) )
        {
            while(precedence(stack[top])-precedence(ip[i])>0 || top!=-1 )
            {
                strcat(op,&ip[i]);
                pop(stack);
            }
            push(stack,ip[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            push(stack,ip[i]);
        }

    }
    //printf("%s ",op);
}
```

While I compile and run. I get a very [strange looking symbol](http://s27.postimg.org/gi8wmrmw3/oie_cg1d_FUWb0_AR4.png) in my output.

Can someone tell me what the heck is that? How do I rectify it?

Comment: its a non printable character, probably something between ascii 0 to 40

Comment: Looks like a what FireFox would use to display non-printable character U+0001. Rectify it by not outputting the byte with value `1`. Find out which of your output statements is emitting it, then find out why the var being printed doesn't contain what you expect it to contain

Comment: tesseract means 40 octal, which is 20 hex, and he literally meant "between" since 40 octal is a space.

Comment: I don't actually have time to look at this, but a quick guess is that `stack[r] == 1` when it should be `stack[r] == '1'`, or `printf("%c\n",stack[r]);` should be `printf("%d\n", (int)(stack[r]));`

Comment: Note: you shouldn't be using `strcat` to add one character. Use `op[j++] = ip[i];`, and finish with `op[j] = '\0';`

Comment: "Strange symbols output" normally means that you are mixing up `char` used as characters with `char` used as small integers. Best use different types to prevent accidents.

Comment: @ikegami:  Shucks, That makes a lot of sense. I completely forgot about it. I've used that now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The code appends to an unitialiised variable and with this provokes undefined behaviour here:

```
  char op[size];

  ...

      strcat(op, ...);
```

To fix this initialise `op` properly to all `0`s, by doing so:

```
  char op[size];
  memset(op, 0, size);
```

---

Also: `precedence()` misses to return any value in case none of the conditions are met.

Add a final `return` statement, like

```
int precedence(const char c)
{
  ...

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I corrected precedence(). I still don't get it, Is it some special character that is always outputted when a variable isn't initialized or its only for strings and characters?

Comment: @user248884: Reading an uninitialised variables provokes undefined behaviuor of the program, so in fact anything could happen. Striklty avoid *undefinded behaviour* of a program.